# How ignore Entitlement Process in Salesforce DX CLI?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin, versioning, entitlement-process

I tried many times to ignore the Entitlement process (with versioning enable) and was unable to do it.

All Scratch organizations that I created, after the first push, the first pull return many errors about my Entitlement Processes, saying that my process was not found. How can I ignore all the Entitlement Processes in `sfdx force:source:pull`?

Here is the scratch-config.json

```
{
"orgName": "Leonardo",
"edition": "Enterprise",
"features": ["PersonAccounts", "ServiceCloud", "Entitlements", "Communities", "PartnerCommunity", "MarketingUser", "ServiceUser", "LiveAgent", "Chatbot", "SalesWave", "ServiceWave"],
"settings": {
    "omniChannelSettings": {
        "enableOmniChannel": true,
        "enableOmniAutoLoginPrompt": true,
        "enableOmniSkillsRouting": true
    },
    "experienceBundleSettings": {
        "enableExperienceBundleMetadata": true
    },
    "communitiesSettings": {
        "enableNetworksEnabled": true
    },
    "entitlementSettings": {
        "enableEntitlements": true,
        "enableEntitlementVersioning": true
    }
},
   "language": "pt_BR"
}
```

Comment: How is it getting enabled in scratch org? Can you specify repro steps?

Comment: 1- I create a new scratch org:
2- Pushed my local project to org.
3- Pull the source to my local project.

Example of error message when I did the pull:
ERROR running force:source:pull:  Entity of type 'EntitlementProcess' named 'assistência técnica - geral' cannot be found
I tried the API name with version, without and nothing .-.

Comment: Can you tell me your sfdx-confit.json

Comment: {"orgName":"Leonardo","edition":"Enterprise","features":["PersonAccounts","ServiceCloud","Entitlements","Communities","PartnerCommunity","MarketingUser","ServiceUser","LiveAgent","Chatbot","SalesWave","ServiceWave"],"settings":{"omniChannelSettings":{"enableOmniChannel":true,"enableOmniAutoLoginPrompt":true,"enableOmniSkillsRouting":true},"experienceBundleSettings":{"enableExperienceBundleMetadata":true},"communitiesSettings":{"enableNetworksEnabled":true},"entitlementSettings":{"enableEntitlements":true,"enableEntitlementVersioning":true}},"language":"pt_BR"}